# How can I quickly make a large file?

Tags: files, disk-usage

What is a quick and easy way to make a file that is, say, 2 GB in size?

Answer (score 40, accepted):

The [zero-fill method](https://askubuntu.com/questions/47963/how-can-i-quickly-make-a-large-file/47964#47964) (here modified to avoid [potential memory bottlenecks](https://askubuntu.com/questions/47963/how-can-i-quickly-make-a-large-file/48537?noredirect=1#comment1411072_48537)) took 17 seconds to create a 10 GB file on an SSD and caused Ubuntu's graphical interface to become unresponsive.

```
$ time sh -c 'dd if=/dev/zero iflag=count_bytes count=10G bs=1M of=large; sync'
10240+0 records in
10240+0 records out
10737418240 bytes (11 GB, 10 GiB) copied, 17.2003 s, 624 MB/s

real    0m17.642s
user    0m0.008s
sys     0m9.404s
$ du -B 1 --apparent-size large
10737418240     large
$ du -B 1 large
10737422336     large
```

[fallocate](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/en/man1/fallocate.1.html) creates large files instantly by directly manipulating the file's allocated disk space:

```
$ time sh -c 'fallocate -l 10G large; sync'

real    0m0.038s
user    0m0.000s
sys     0m0.016s
$ du -B 1 --apparent-size large
10737418240     large
$ du -B 1 large
10737422336     large
```

[truncate](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/en/man1/truncate.1.html) also works instantly, and creates [sparse files](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sparse_file) which don't use up actual disk space until data is written later on:

```
$ time sh -c 'truncate -s 10G large; sync'

real    0m0.014s
user    0m0.000s
sys     0m0.004s
$ du -B 1 --apparent-size large
10737418240     large
$ du -B 1 large
0       large
```

Comment: `dd ... bs=2G count=1` reads 2 GB into memory (in one `read(2)` call). If you've got memory pressure that's probably not the way to go. More, smaller blocks may be faster if it means less paging.

Answer (score 22):

An easy way would be to use the `dd` command to write a file full of zeros.

```
dd if=/dev/zero of=outputFile bs=2G count=1
```

- if = input file
- of = output file
- bs = bytes

Use G in the size argument if you want computer (1024*1024*1024) gigabytes, or GB if you want human (1000*1000*1000) gigabytes.

Comment: i will just add that if you dont want all zeros, you can choose 
if=/dev/random

Comment: Though /dev/random will take more time.

Comment: Using /dev/random will take an *awful* lot of time. Use `/dev/urandom` in that case (it's non-blocking, but not guaranteed to have the same level of randomness). Drawing 2 GB from either one will almost certainly completely exhaust your system's entropy, so don't do anything cryptographic for a while afterwards.

Answer (score 1):

ftp://ftp.fsf.hu/testfiles/maketestfiles.sh

or Seek is the size of the file you want in bytes - 1.

```
dd if=/dev/zero of=filename.big bs=1 count=1 seek=1048575 # 1 MByte

dd if=/dev/zero of=filename.big bs=1 count=1 seek=10485759 # 10 MByte

dd if=/dev/zero of=filename.big bs=1 count=1 seek=104857599 # 100 MByte

dd if=/dev/zero of=filename.big bs=1 count=1 seek=1073741823 # 1024 MByte

dd if=/dev/zero of=filename.big bs=1 count=1 seek=42949672959 # 40960 MByte
```