# How to re-enable hibernate option?

Tags: 12.10, hibernate

I had enabled "hibernate" option in my Ubuntu 12.10 few months back by adding the following lines to `/etc/polkit-1/localauthority/50-local.d/com.ubuntu.enable-hibernate.pkla`:

```
[Re-enable hibernate by default]
Identity=unix-user:*
Action=org.freedesktop.upower.hibernate
ResultActive=yes
```

However, I don't know how, rather don't remember what led to it being disabled both in "power options" and in the "gear icon" on the menu bar.

The file is still intact.

One of the things I suspect is removing old kernels using Ubuntu tweak, but have no valid reason to allege this :P

Comment: try this [How to Enable Hibernation in Ubuntu](http://ktechpit.org/how-to-enable-hibernation-in-ubuntu-14-04/)

Comment: I had to create that policy file in `/var/lib` instead of `/etc` (Ubuntu 14.04). After `killall unity-panel-service` it immediately appeared under the gear menu.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ghosh... how did I take so long in discovering that I didn't have an entry for the swap partition in my `/etc/fstab` file?

The problem was, I had deleted my swap partition and then  re-created it some days later, but did not realize that `/etc/fstab` had the old entry and the newer one was never added to it.

[Adding the entry](https://askubuntu.com/questions/126018/adding-a-new-swap-file-how-to-edit-fstab-to-enable-swap-after-reboot) and rebooting my laptop now gives me the option to hibernate.

Answer (score 0):

Try running `sudo update-grub`, occasionally this is necessary if you change grub settings or configurations. From the highest searched answer to this question: ([How to enable hibernation?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/94754/how-to-enable-hibernation)) "Some users will then need to run sudo update-grub to get the hibernate option to be available in the power menu.."

Comment: Thanks @handuel, but there is no change.

Comment: @Jobin Well, there would be no change. `grub` is the bootloader for Ubuntu (To Dual-Boot), so no change would happen.

Comment: @nerof61 I quote: "Some users will then need to run sudo update-grub to get the hibernate option to be available in the power menu.."

Comment: Hmm... true...!