# Should the swap area for ubuntu go on my ssd or hdd?

Tags: partitioning, hard-drive, ssd, swap

I just bought the samsung 960 evo 250gb and am reinstalling windows 10 and ubuntu 16.04.

1. How big should I make the partition for ubuntu on the ssd? Is 10gb enough for the OS and future updates?
2. Should the swap area be on the ssd or the hdd?
3. When I install windows 10 and ubuntu on the ssd how do I set it so my c drive is the hdd, so when I download stuff it will default to my hdd unless I change it before downloading?
4. Should I have two separate partitions on the hdd to separate windows files and ubuntu files?

Comment: writing to ssd shortens its lifespan. So it is recommended to not place on it partitions with frequent write operations like cache partitions.  http://www.pcworld.com/article/2043634/how-to-stretch-the-life-of-your-ssd-storage.html

Comment: Partial answer already here: https://askubuntu.com/questions/352131/put-swap-on-ssd-or-hdd?rq=1

Comment: Also see https://askubuntu.com/questions/652337/why-no-swap-partitions-on-ssd-drives

Answer (score 5):

Assuming data partitions will be on the HDD

1) I would give Ubuntu 50GB minimum (10GB isn't enough for an install)

2) Swap should be on the HDD. SDD life is determined by writes, so only things that do not change frequently should be there.

3)  C: in windows is always the partition that it loaded from. you will have to set the download location in your software.

4)  Linux can mount NTFS partitions, but I would have 3 partitions. one for windows, one for Linux, and one for sharing files. the share partition needs to be formatted NTFS.

Note: quick boot in windows should be turned off if sharing a partition. Because quick boot is really a hibernate, sharing a partition with it turned on could cause file system errors on the shared partition.

Comment: 1) Ubuntu *can* be installed on 10GB or even less. It is not too useful if you plan to install some more programs and want to put your personal data there too, but it all depends on the use case. // 4) You don't *really* need an extra partition, you can just let Ubuntu directly access the main Windows partition to exchange data. It's okay and a good idea if you have much "shared" data, but not a requirement. // Note: Ubuntu can mount hibernated Windows partitions read-only if you tell it to do so, without causing any harm. You can just not write to it.

Comment: @ByteCommander -- yes with a separate /home it can be installed in 10GB (my root uses 6GB) but a couple kernel updates and is is full. Having a share partition read only kind of defeats the purpose of a shared partition.

Comment: the ubuntu operating system is going on the ssd, then whenever I download a program for ubuntu like gimp, google chrome, or atom should I install those on the ssd or hdd?

Comment: @idknuttin -- ubuntu (linux) installs to specific folders. if you are savy with linux you could make these folders as separate partitions on the HDD. It is fine for the programs to be on the SDD, but put data folder on HDD