# Extremely slow OS. Swap related?

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, hard-drive, swap, ram

I really hope you can help me. An inexperienced sysadmin, installed Ubuntu on a new Dell Desktop, it's a pretty powerful machine, and I ran a bunch of hardware tests, and can confirm that RAM/HDD and the whole lot works as expected.

He installed ubuntu 14.10 alongside windows8 and he told me that he made some mistake with the encrypted swap partition.

In fact there was no swap partition, I created one and went on with my life.

I've been using this machine for 5 months now, and between massive databases and finely tuned services I would like to avoid a format if possible, but the computer is extremely slow, as soon as the ram gets filled (chrome tabs are the prime example) or the hard disk gets over a certain usage, the computer grinds to a halt, often just hanging for minutes.

I might be inclined to say that somehow the swap partition is not working properly, ram offloads, hard disk shoots up to insanely high usage and the machine just hangs.

I have big knowledge gaps on linux related troubleshooting, can someone help me pointing me in the right direction?

Any help/ideas/tests to run will be greatly appreciated!

Thank you heaps for your time!

Comment: I often run into slow processing when I have hit the swap limit, but I'm also running a laptop and expect some performance issues.  I have mitigated a lot of these using the kernal parameters `noautogroup elevator=cfq` changing both the method of setting process priority, and the disk queuing.

Comment: To see whether swap is used at all issue `free` in a terminal. To create and mount a swap partition see http://askubuntu.com/a/33703/3940 or http://askubuntu.com/a/126049/3940 for using a file as swap.

Comment: It could easily be IOWAIT related see: http://serverfault.com/questions/396443/diagnosing-high-cpu-waiting