# ImageMagick convert and low RAM

Tags: 14.04, amazon-ec2, imagemagick, image-processing

Please consider the following command for the imagemagick package:

```
sudo convert -resize 460x200 /path/to/test1.jpg /path/to/test2.jpg
```

Now `test1.jpg` is a *fairly* large image (12.5MB), but not unheard of sizes, but the server I am working from only has 1G of memory ([Amazon EC2](https://aws.amazon.com/ec2/) [t2.micro](https://aws.amazon.com/ec2/instance-types/) if it helps)

No error is being thrown, and yet no `test2.jpg` is being created. I have tested this with smaller images and it works fine. I would have thought 1G if memory would be plenty to manage a resize, but perhaps not?

What are my options, do I have to get more memory or am I missing something?

Any suggestions are very welcome!

**Requested Edits**

strace output shows: `+++ killed by SIGKILL +++` along with *alot* of commands that look normal (opening `/usr/share/local` and reading long strings, which I assume is image data)

free gives me:

```
         total       used       free     shared    buffers     cached
Mem:       1016292     278348     737944       6412        460      13356
-/+ buffers/cache:     264532     751760
Swap:            0          0          0
```

So it looks as if swap is not enabled, so I will look into creating a swapfile to see if this sorts my issues.

File gives me:

```
testprint10Mbv2.jpg: JPEG image data, EXIF standard
```

I would also paste the full /path/to/img but unfortunately it contains sensitive data (client email addresses etc)

Comment: Why are you using `sudo` in this command?

Comment: Received "Killed" message when I didn't

Comment: What s the output of `uname -a`?

Comment: Linux ip-xxx-31-25-220 3.13.0-48-generic #80-Ubuntu SMP Thu Mar 12 11:16:15 UTC 2015 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

Comment: Weird - perhaps there is something in the "killed" error message that gives a clue as to the problem.

Comment: I did have a look-see and found that 'Killed' is from a daemon that kills memory-intensive processes, I tried a couple work-arounds but to no avail. :(

Comment: You could try to replace `convert` with `mogrify` **on a copy** of your image.

Comment: @Takkat, I did try this previously and got the same result

Comment: Ypu can try to limit the memory used for the pixel cache with the argument `-limit memory 64MiB` (32MiB is a bit too small probably. Default is 1.5GiB). And it should give you some descriptive output in case it fails.

Comment: I hardly dare to ask, but did you try to press F5 (refresh nautilus)? It happened to me several times that I did not *see* the converted or created file under certain circumstances, but it was nevertheless created. Shortage of memory seems to be a logical reason for this to happen.

Comment: @dadexix86 I will give this a shot and come back with any results I get when I am back in-office, thanks.

Comment: @JacobVlijm I'm not running GUI, I'm doing the commands from putty and checking the file system from WinSCP FTP client, but Yeah I am refreshing WinSCP, good question though, thats caught me out before :P

Comment: Try running the command with `strace` appended in front of the command, see what system calls are made, errors thrown. Let us know

Comment: Is there swap enabled on the system? I would like to see an [edit] that included the output of `free` and also `file /path/to/test1.jpg`

Comment: @Aphire any news on this?

Comment: @dadexix86 I tried what you suggested but unfortunately got the same outcome

Comment: I can confirm adding a swap file has solved the issue. @ElderGeek If you would submit this as an answer I will gladly accept as your comment led me to find the correct answer.

Comment: Done. I'm glad you got it resolved! the free output confirms that swap is off and the file info confirms that it's not a mis-identified file. Nice edit! +1

Comment: What are the dimensions of the image in pixels? "12.5Mb" does not tell much as it the size of compressed data which needs to be de-compressed to be resized. 10.000 x 10.000 pixels image would require 400Mb of RAM (4 bytes per pixel), and can be easily compressed to a few Mb if it is mostly solid color.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'm assuming you are running out of RAM. You can verify this with `watch cat /proc/meminfo` while your process is running.

You may have insufficient RAM and/or SWAP to accomplish your task.

Due to the low-ram condition, insure that swap is on with `swapon -a` and if no swap is setup on the system create a partition for swap on unused diskspace and enable it. This will likely solve the problem. There's a good answer by @Takkat on how to do that [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/33697/how-do-i-add-a-swap-partition-after-system-installation) If you don't have access to partitioning the server you can also use a [swapfile for swap](https://askubuntu.com/questions/126018/adding-a-new-swap-file-how-to-edit-fstab-to-enable-swap-after-reboot/126049#126049)

Comment: OP is about a cloud server, creating a swap partition may not be an option. You may add [How to add new swap file](https://askubuntu.com/questions/126018/adding-a-new-swap-file-how-to-edit-fstab-to-enable-swap-after-reboot/126049#126049) too.

Comment: @Sneetsher Thats exactly what I did, good comment

Comment: @Sneetsher "OP is about a cloud server" wasn't clear (at least to me) from the data in the question but you make a good point. editing answer.

Comment: @ElderGeek , actually it is but not well highlighted `Amazon EC2 t2.micro` , I edited question to make clear, added tag too to be easy linked to other related questions.

Comment: @Sneetsher I see that now. Thank you for your efforts!

Answer (score 7):

The issue in the question was resolved by adding appropriate swap. For completeness let me give a summary of additional options we have when running Image Magick `convert` on huge files on low memory systems, or when there is no swap available, or the swap was too small.

The methods mentioned below are elaborated in detail in the Image Magick manual:

#### [Really Massive Image Handling](http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/files/#massive)

---

Summary:

1. **Limit memory usage with option [`-limit`](http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/option_link.cgi?limit)**

   By doing so Image Magick will create a temporary file for image handling as soon as the given memory limits were exceeded. This needs write permission for Image Magick on the temporary file directory. We can give any path where the temporary file will be created in an environment variable `MAGICK_TMPDIR`. An example command may look similar to this:

   ```
       env MAGICK_TMPDIR=/tempdir nice -5 convert -limit memory 32 -limit map 32 largefile.jpg -resize 640x320 smallfile.png
   ```

   Working on disk rather than in RAM will slow down the processing speed considerably.
2. **Work with "Memory Mapped Disk Files"**

   Creating MPC files is resource demanding but it does not need so much resources to convert from MPC files. Therefore is may be put into consideration in case we need to convert the same source with different parameters several times. The workflow may then be similar to this:

   ```
   convert huge.jpg huge.mpc
   convert huge.mpc -resize 50% big.png
   convert huge.mpc -resize 20% small.png
   convert huge.mpc -resize 5% thumb.png
   ```
3. **Work on small sections of an image using [`stream`](http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/basics/#stream)**

   Using **stream** claims to only process a part of the source image without the need to load the whole image into memory.

   ```
   stream -map rgb -storage-type char -extract 600x400+1900+2900 image.png - | convert -depth 8 -size 600x400 rgb:- tile.png
   ```

   In above example the `-extract` option takes size and offset values as defined by the Image Magick [geometry](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/command-line-processing.php#geometry). We will have to stick the tiles back together for getting the scaled image as a whole. Unfortunately **stream** does not work for all image formats but is supposed to work fine on JPEG images.