# Swap file not activated on startup on Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: swap

I have created swapfile at /swapfile and add following line to /etc/fstab (according to [SwapFaq](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SwapFaq)):

```
/swapfile                                 none            swap    sw  0  0
```

When I try to activate it with `sudo swapon --all`, everything is fine, but it does not activated after reboot, `sudo swapon --show` shows nothing. Again, activating it with `sudo swapon --all` works. What am I doing wrong? How to activate swap file on system start?

Comment: All looks right except for the failing auto-activation during startup. Double-check your `fstab` whether indeed you correctly entered that line in the correct file.

Comment: Can you expand on how to do that?

Comment: @salmmus Here: https://askubuntu.com/questions/126018/adding-a-new-swap-file-how-to-edit-fstab-to-enable-swap-after-reboot