# How to create hundred thousand (100,000) files with extension of “.jpg”, ‘.c’, ‘.sh’?

Tags: command-line, files

How to create hundred thousand (100,000) files in a directory with extension of each `.jpg`, `.c`, `.sh`?

The size of each file will be 5kb and each extension will have 33,333 files.

Comment: yeah, i have searched quite a lot

Comment: Also your question is not very clear..you want 100000 copies of each extension? what about the varying sizes?

Comment: i want a total 100,000 files, with extensions of .jpg, .c, .sh

Comment: What would be proportion then? also what about the sizes?

Comment: all sizes between 1kb and 10 kb. proportion may be 33,333

Comment: There is no may be..put a strict condition on number of files and sizes..

Comment: ok, the size is 5kb, and the total number of files are 33,333*3 (multiplied by 3 for .jpg .c .sh)

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add this info..

Comment: do you know the answer?

Comment: then i am doing it

Answer (score 9):

There are many ways to do this:

- Using `head` with a simple `for` construct:

  ```
  for ext in jpg c sh; do head -c 5K /dev/zero >{1..33333}."$ext"; done
  ```

  Similarly `tail -c 5K` would work also.
- Using `dd`:

  ```
  for ext in jpg c sh; do dd if=/dev/zero bs=1K count=5 >{1..33333}."$ext"; done
  ```
- Using `truncate` (this would create sparse files):

  ```
  for ext in jpg c sh; do truncate -s 5K {1..33333}."$ext"; done
  ```

All of the above will create files with extensions `.sh`, `.c` and `.jpg`. Each file will be of 5KB and each extension will have 33,333 files.

Comment: +1 for `truncate` - another quick method would be `fallocate`. See http://askubuntu.com/questions/47963/how-can-i-quickly-make-a-large-file

Comment: @Takkat Thought about `fallocate` but it does not take multiple filenames as argument so will be very very slow in this case..hence did not bother to mention it..

Answer (score 1):

This would help :

```
mkdir my100000files
cd my100000files/
touch aa
```

Now write anything in aa to make it 1KB to 10KB

```
for FILE in `seq 00000 33333`; do cp aa $FILE.c; done
```

Do the same for .sh and jpg